# Completely unable to login

Tags: 14.04, login, password, lightdm

I've been trying to add more security to passwords, etc.  I did the following things (in Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS)

in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`, added (as first line)

```
auth required pam_tally.so onerr=fail deny=3 unlock_time=3600 magic_root
```

in `/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure sha512 minlen=14 remember=24 audit
```

in `/etc/login.defs`

```
PASS_MAX_DAYS 60 
PASS_MIN_DAYS 1 
PASS_WARN_AGE 14 
LOG_OK_LOGINS yes
SULOG_FILE /var/log/sulog 
SYSLOG_SU_ENAB yes 
SYSLOG_SG_ENAB yes
```

I cannot log in from either the GUI or the text console.  I dropped into the root shell from recovery mode, did `mount -rw -o /` and tried both changing my password and creating a new user, no joy.

What did I screw up?  Please and thank you.

Comment: Did you reboot after all this?

Comment: I did.  Multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through extensive trial and error, it appears that the culprit was

```
auth required pam_tally.so onerr=fail deny=3 unlock_time=3600 magic_root
```

Removing

```
deny=3 unlock_time=3600
```

and instead doing

```
sudo faillog -l 3600 -m 3
```

appears to have done the trick.

I would still like to understand why, if anyone can offer an explanation.  I chose those options based on the pam_tally man page.